# Ignore str in sum()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists containing predominantly numeric values. I need to find the highest value, determine the index of that list it contains, and sum up all values in that list.

I have this code that works fine:

```
results = [[213, 124, 100],
           [123.7, 444.6, 111, 12],
           [],
           [22, 11, 100, 2],
           [-1000]]

highest, row, total = -1, 0, 0
for a, b in enumerate(results):
    for i in b:
        if i > highest:
            highest = i
            row = a
            total = sum(b)
```

The problem is that I need to make sure, that the algorithm does not break if one of the values is a string.
Is there a way to ignore strings in sum, or I'd need to iterate through b as well and check for strings?

Comment: You initialize highest with zero, yet your list of lists can contain negative values. If all the values turn out negative, your code erroneously returns zero.

Comment: The correct way would generally be to use a try/except, not being a str does not make something a number

Comment: Why are any of the values strings? That's usually the kind of situation where you'd *want* your program to abort with a `TypeError`, so you can notice the problem and fix it.

Comment: How does  `total = sum(b)` work? You are continually looping even if you find a higher value and calling sum every time you find one

Comment: good point @bipll, thanks!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Yes, I need the total for that list only where the highest value is. So it works fine.

Comment: @Zorgmorduk. You are summing the same sublist  every time  `i > highest:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already iterating through `b`; just check each value is not a string *then*. But yes, when using `sum` you need to filter out values that are strings too, use a generator expression:

```
for a, b in enumerate(results):
    for i in b:
        if not isinstance(i, str) and i > highest:
            highest = i
            row = a
            total = sum(i for i in b if not isinstance(i, str))
```

You could inverse the test and make sure the value is an int or float instead:

```
for a, b in enumerate(results):
    for i in b:
        if isinstance(i, (int, float)) and i > highest:
            highest = i
            row = a
            total = sum(i for i in b if isinstance(i, (int, float)))
```

It'd be much better if you could ensure the lists contained only numbers up front however:

```
highest, row, total = 0, 0, 0
filtered_results = [[i for i in b if isinstance(i, (int, float))] for b in results]
for a, b in enumerate(filtered_results):
    for i in b:
        if i > highest:
            highest = i
            row = a
            total = sum(b)
```

Comment: Well, the total = sum(for i in b if not isinstance(i, str)) does not work

Comment: @Zorgmorduk, that is because it should be `sum(i for i in b if not isinstance(i, str)) `, you need the `i` at the start

Comment: @Zorgmorduk: mea culpa, typo; there was an `i` missing at the start.

Comment: Thanks for both of you! Yes, this later one works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the index and the sublist with the highest single value:

```
results = [[213, 124, 100],
           [123.7, 444.6, 111, 12],
           [],
           [22, 11, 100, 2],
           [-1000]]

def try_mx(x):
    try:
        return max((i for i in x[1] if isinstance(i, (int, float))))
    except ValueError:
        return float("-inf")

mx_ind = max(enumerate(results), key=try_mx)


print(mx_ind)
```

Which will give you the index and the sublist:

```
 (1, [123.7, 444.6, 111, 12])
```

In your own code every time `if i > highest` is True you call sum, sum should only be called once per sublist  if you found a higher value not every time you find a higher value.

You can use *max* again so you call sum only if the highest value is greater than the current highest, using python3 you can give max a default to catch your empty lists:

```
highest, row, total = float("-inf"), 0, 0
for a, b in enumerate(results):
    mx = max((i for i in b if isinstance(i, (int,float))), default=float("-inf"))
    if mx > highest:
        highest = mx
        row = a
        total = sum(b)
```